# How to specify Solution file in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am having trouble configuring an Azure DevOps Dotnet core build process.

I have a simple dotnet core project which I am attempting to build in an Azure DevOps environment.

The project is in a subfolder within my repo, but I cannot figure out how to specify how the Pipeline should find my csproj file.  [The MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=vsts) suggests that you can specify it but there are no examples and all of my attempts are met with errors.

When building a pipeline with the standard dotnet CLI template, the YAML created is:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core web applications targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/vsts/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

However this is met with the error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. 
The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

The documentation linked above suggests using a "task" based syntax rather than a script, and I assume that in the documentation the inputs are listed in the same order as the examples listed underneath.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use the `script` you specify the csproj file after the `build` word:

```
- script: dotnet build myrepo/test/test.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
```

The best way to use Azure DevOps Pipeline is to use tasks for the build pipeline, in the Dotnet Core yaml build task you specify the file in the `inputs` section:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build' 
    projects: 'myrepo/test/test.csproj'
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought Tasks looked like a better option, yet the built in Designer for pipelines on Azure Devops creates a YAML using the dotnet build script for some reason.  With your example I've successfully created a build task using the DotnetCoreCLI task.